# Jenkins: Python + Selenium

Tags: python, bash, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

I've been looking around for a simple step-by-step tutorial on how to configure selenium tests to be run with Jenkins, but honestly I didn't find anything special.

I have a bash script by whom the test are run. The test are written in Python. I found out it's possible to run them, but I couldn't figure out to configure it properly.

I found that video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lP_VUP0YF0 , but there's been skipped the configuration.

Would anyone give me some tips or even write a simple tutorial ?
Thanks a lot for all answers!

Answer (score 0):

> I have a bash script by whom the test are run

In its simplest form, that's what you need to put in your Jenkins job.

1. Create a job which can access all your code, probably via a git, svn or mercurial repository (or a shared drive)

   - and either have it execute your bash script via "Add step --> bash command", or
2. Put each step of your bash script as a bash step in your job.

You're not going to get a tutorial here. Better to try something here and then ask a specific question.